# Error in Code when input is correct

Tags: python

Im making a simple game as my first project in Python. I'm having a problem with this code:

```
invalid=True
def start():
    x=input('Enter the Keyword:')
    if ("m" == x) or ("M"==x):
        print('Correct!')
    elif x!='m' or x!='M':
        print('Invalid Input.')
        invalid=False
    while invalid:
        start()
```

When the user's input is correct the program still asks again for the input..

How do I continue with the next lines of code when the input is correct?

Comment: format your code properly please

Comment: Are you sure you posted your indentation correctly?

Comment: You need to use a loop. That could be `for i in range(0,10):` if you know how many riddles to ask, or `while True:` if you want to ask forever.

Comment: all that code of yours can just be converted to `while input('Enter the Keyword:').lower() != 'm': continue`

Comment: If you want to get out of the loop when it's correct, you'll have to change invalid to False, if the lines of code are below those you're showing to us.

Comment: Indenting with a single space does not make readable code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable `invalid` inside the function is local to the function (since you made an assignment which hides the global var) and doesn't affect the global variable.

Simple solution is to declare `invalid` as global inside function `start`.

```
def start():
    global invalid
    ...
    ...
    invalid=False
```

So the code looks like

```
invalid=True
def start():
    global invalid
    x=input('Enter the Keyword:')
    if ("m" == x) or ("M"==x):
        print('Correct!')
    elif x!='m' or x!='M':
        print('Invalid Input.')
        invalid=False
while invalid:
    start()
```

Comment: Or even prefferably get rid of this global variable by using return value or other suolution. Anyway +1